# Spring Unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When I start my application as Spring Boot application, ServiceEndpointConfig gets autowired properly. But when I run as Junit test, I get the following exception. I am using application.yml file and different profiles.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyServiceContextConfig.class, 
loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class) 
@ActiveProfiles({"unit", "statsd-none"})
public class MyServiceTest
{
}

@Configuration
public class MyServiceContextConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyService myServiceImpl(){
        return new MyServiceImpl();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan("com.myservice")
@Import({ServiceEndpointConfig.class})
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

   @Autowired
   ServiceEndpointConfig serviceEndpointConfig;

}

@Configuration
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="service")
public class ServiceEndpointConfig
{
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceImpl': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serviceEndpointConfig': No qualifying bean of type [com.myservice.config.ServiceEndpointConfig] found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're handling `MyServiceImpl` inconsistently: On the one hand, you're using scanning annotations, and on the other, you're explicitly creating an `@Bean` in a configuration class. The import directive is only processed when Spring picks `MyServiceImpl` up via scanning; otherwise, it's not treated as a configuration.

Your relationships between the classes are tangled up; the whole point of dependency injection is that `MyServiceImpl` should say *what sort of thing* it needs but not create it itself. This organization is no better than manually creating dependencies internally.

Instead,

- eliminate the `@Configuration` and `@Import` directives from `MyServiceImpl`,
- use constructor injection on `MyServiceImpl`, and
- change *your test configuration* to include all the necessary configuration classes.

With constructor injection, you may be able to bypass the Spring context entirely and run this as an actual *unit* test by simply creating a `new MyServiceImpl(testServiceConfig)`.